# left_join by categories and range values

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I want to `left_join` two dataframes.

```
pensions <- data.frame(gender = c(rep("Female", 3 ), (rep("Male", 2 ) )), 
                   age = c(66,69,72,85,62), 
                   type = c(rep("widow",2), rep("disability", 2 ), "old age"))




gender  <- c(rep("Female", 12), rep("Male", 12))
type    <- rep(c(rep("widow",4), rep("disability",4), rep("old_age",4)),2)
min_age <- rep(c(65,seq(76, 99, by = 10)),6)
max_age <- rep(c(seq(75, 99, by = 10),99),6)
factor   <- c(435,215,415,89,10,45,36,74,98,15,27,23,
         117,343,201,58,41,95,777,65,21,57,13,6)


pension_factors <- data.frame(gender, type, min_age, max_age, factor )
```

The first dataframe **pensions** contains the columns *gender*, *age*, and  *type*. The latter reoresents the type of pension.

The second dataframe **pension_factors** contains the columns *gender*, *type*, *min_age*, *max_age*, and  *factor*.

How do I `left_join` **pensions** with **pension_factors** in a way that I  `left_join` by *gender* and *type* and the age of `pensions$age`  is equal or greater than `pension_factors$min_age` but less than or equal to `pension_factors$max_age`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to join and then filter the joined data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(pensions, pension_factors, by=c('gender', 'type')) %>%
    filter(age >= min_age,
           age <= max_age)

  gender age       type min_age max_age factor
1 Female  66      widow      65      75    435
2 Female  69      widow      65      75    435
3 Female  72 disability      65      75     10
4   Male  85 disability      76      85     95
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `fuzzyjoin`:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)
fuzzy_left_join(
    pensions %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character),
    pension_factors %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character),
    by = c(
        "gender" = "gender",
        "type" = "type",
        "age" = "min_age",
        "age" = "max_age"),
    match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`))
#  gender.x age     type.x gender.y     type.y min_age max_age factor
#1   Female  66      widow   Female      widow      65      75    435
#2   Female  69      widow   Female      widow      65      75    435
#3   Female  72 disability   Female disability      65      75     10
#4     Male  85 disability     Male disability      76      85     95
#5     Male  62    old age     <NA>       <NA>      NA      NA     NA
```

Explanation: `by` lists all columns by which we match, and `match_fun` lists the corresponding matching conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can first merge the two datasets:

```
mergeddf<-merge(x=pensions,y=pension_factors,by.x=c("gender", "type"),by.y=c("gender", "type"),all.x = TRUE)
```

then only take a subset of the merged dataset in which the age is between min and max age:

```
finaldf<-mergeddf[which(mergeddf$age>=mergeddf$min_age & mergeddf$age<=mergeddf$max_age),]
     #  gender       type age min_age max_age factor
     #1 Female disability  72      65      75     10
     #5 Female      widow  66      65      75    435
     #9 Female      widow  69      65      75    435
     #14  Male disability  85      76      85     95
```